# A problem in my code, how to check if variable exists or not

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, pyaudio

full code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
adLoop = True

detector = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as source:
    detector.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    print("Please speak: ")
    audio = detector.listen(source)
    print("Recognizing...")
    final_text = detector.recognize_google(audio)
    print(f"Converted speech: {final_text}")

    while adLoop:

        print("Would you like to convert more words to text?: Y/N")
        test_audio = detector.listen(source)
        test_text = detector.recognize_google(test_audio)
        if test_text == "yes":
            adLoop = True
            print("go on")
            audio_two = detector.listen(source)
            print("Recognizing...")
            final_text_two = detector.recognize_google(audio_two)
            print(f"Current text: {final_text} {final_text_two}")
        elif test_text == "no" and len(final_text_two) > 1:
            adLoop = False
            print(f"Everything is done, the final text looks like: {final_text} {final_text_two}")    
        elif test_text == "no":
            adLoop = False
            print(f"Everything is done, the final text looks like: {final_text}")
        elif test_text != "yes" or "no":
            print("Something went wrong...Please repeat(Answer Yes or No only)")
            adLoop = True
```

Hello, is it somehow possible to check if final_text_two exists or not in case it was not entered by the user so line 30 can work after line 27. I'm currently getting the error if final_text_two was not entered.

```
if test_text == "yes":
            adLoop = True
            print("go on")
            audio_two = detector.listen(source)
            print("Recognizing...")
            final_text_two = detector.recognize_google(audio_two)
            print(f"Current text: {final_text} {final_text_two}")
        elif test_text == "no" and len(final_text_two) > 1:
            adLoop = False
            print(f"Everything is done, the final text looks like: {final_text} {final_text_two}")    
        elif test_text == "no":
            adLoop = False
            print(f"Everything is done, the final text looks like: {final_text}")
```

Comment: It's easy to check if variable exists, for example `"myvar" in vars()`, but don't do it, better use boolean flag and don't build the logic on existing of variables but on the value of them

Comment: Understood, ty for the help.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how that library works, but you could probably use try and except.

```
try:
     print(f"Everything is done, the final text looks like: {final_text} {final_text_two}")

except:
    print("Nothing entered.")
```

Comment: Ugh, my bad. Now the while loop does not end, it did not work.